# Often seeing "REPL command timed out" in Cider with shadow-cljs and React Native. Must restart emulator to fix

Tags: react-native, cider, shadow-cljs

I'm working with a basic ReactNative app using Emacs with Cider and ShadowCLJS. I can develop with the REPL pretty consistently but as soon as I accidentally save a file that has a syntax error in it then I lose communication to the REPL. Anything I type results in a delay followed by "REPL command timed out". The only way I have found to fix it is to restart the emulator with `npx react-native run-android`. But then I lose all the state that I had in the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a number of different things.

It might related to the live-reloading that Metro (or Expo) provides. Press Ctrl-M (Cmd-M on Mac) in the emulator to bring up the options to turn off Fast Refresh.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/fast-refresh

https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/issues/469

If you're still getting this error even after disabling Fast Refresh, it might be because ReactNative doesn't cleanly disconnect old websockets when reloading. Here's a comment from the creator of shadow-cljs.

> its a bug in react-native in that it doesn't disconnect websockets when reloading the app so shadow-cljs thinks the "old" app is still running and tries talking to it (but it never replies) I opened an issue on the RN repo but it was closed due do inactivity for a year or so. nobody cared I guess.

I found a work-around using ReactNative's AppState and the reference to the websocket from the shadow-cljs dev namespace.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/blob/master/src/main/shadow/cljs/devtools/client/react_native.cljs

```
(defn on-app-state-change
  "Fixes issue with shadow-cljs repl losing connection to websocket.

  Put this in some root component's `component-did-mount`.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561073/websocket-not-closed-on-reload-appreact-native
  "
  [state]
  (cond
    (= state "background")
    (.close @shadow-rn/socket-ref)

    (and (= state "active")
         (nil? @shadow-rn/socket-ref))
    (shadow-rn/ws-connect)))

(defn make-reloader
  [component]
  (let [component-ref (r/atom component)]
    (letfn [(render []
              (let [component @component-ref]
                (if (fn? component)
                  (component)
                  component)))]
      (let [wrapper (r/create-class
                     {:render render
                      :component-did-mount
                      (fn []
                        (.addEventListener rn/AppState "change" on-app-state-change))

                      :component-will-unmount
                      (fn []
                        (.removeEventListener rn/AppState "change" on-app-state-change))})]

        (rn/AppRegistry.registerComponent "Ezmonic" (fn [] wrapper))
        (fn [comp]
          (reset! component-ref comp))))))
```

Comment: Just mentioning for easy reference: https://clojurians.slack.com/archives/C0E1SN0NM/p1579005412011800